# my html page has ErrorUtils caught an error: "<![EX[["Tried to listen to element

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have developed a web page with pure HTML CSS and javascript. I have embedded an iFrame of a facebook in to the page with the help of using this link to create it .

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

it gives me a complete iFrame tag to embed in webpage. something like this.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

the problem is that in console of inspect , it has 8 error with this description

`2_lKGfYKUpd.js:55 ErrorUtils caught an error: "<![EX[["Tried to listen to element of type %s from %s: %s","click","Error","C...". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.`

what exactly should I do to solve this problem. 
I appreciate any kind of help. 
Thank you

Comment: This is coming from Facebook’s code, there is nothing you can do about it from your end.

Comment: @misorude thank you very very much . so it feels much better it does not depend on deveoper. just another question , once I checked the web page it said the service is unavailable. I thought it might be because of these erorrs. what do you think with respect!

Comment: @misorude feel free to answer the question if you like  I will accepted. thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is coming from Facebook’s code, there is nothing you can do about it from your end.

They have certain debug measures implemented in their own code, some of which log data to the console.

Some of the functionality of their Social Plugins can also cause errors, resp. is let run into certain errors deliberately, to check whether a certain functionality is available in the browser.

But all of this should not affect the end user. Unless you encounter an error that actually prevents the plugins from working, or even interferes with your own code, there is no real need to take any further action.

Comment: anyone know the correct place on facebook's code infra (github or elsewhere) where I can leave a bug/complaint about this?

Comment: nevermind found it, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/940651616834462/

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when you're not not logged in to Facebook in the same session. To remove this error from console, just logged in to Facebook on another tab in the same window and it should disappear.

Also, as @misorude mentioned, there is nothing to do at your end.